# Elastic Search attempts to parse a non-date filed as date based on its value

Tags: .net, elasticsearch, nest

Using NEST with .NET Core we're getting the following error:

```
failed to parse field [UniqueId] of type [date] in document with id '123456'. Preview of field's value: '4524395.3.6-0'" CausedBy: "Type: illegal_argument_exception Reason: "failed to parse date field [4524395.3.6-0] with format [strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis]" CausedBy: "Type: date_time_parse_exception Reason: "Failed to parse with all enclosed parsers"""
```

`UniqueId` is a string field, here's the part of the index for it:

```
 "UniqueId" : {
                  "type" : "text",
                  "fields" : {
                    "keyword" : {
                      "type" : "keyword",
                      "ignore_above" : 256
                    }
                  }
                },
```

How do we stop elastic from attempting to parse it?

Comment: Can you show what you get when running `GET your-index-name`?  i.e. the real mapping of your index, not the one you think you have installed

Comment: That's what I posted  at the bottom of my post (a fragment of the actual index)

Comment: Somehow ES thinks that `UniqueId` is of type `date`, that's why I wanted to see the real mapping. So, what you're saying is that the mapping you're showing is actually the real one you got from ES and not the one you think you've installed, correct? Can you explain how you are indexing your data? Do you have time-based indexes?

Comment: 100% real. The index is huge and majorly irritant for the issue we have. It looks like elastic tries parsing the value based on its value rather than instructions received from the index.

Comment: Ok, but I don't see how ES would think that `4524395.3.6-0` is a date

Comment: Can you explain how you are indexing your data? Do you have time-based indexes?

Comment: I'm new to elastic, the index was auto-generated based on the object structure we're indexing. Looks like elastic attempts to parse the value based on its pattern rather than on anything else

Comment: Would you mind sharing the full mapping that was generated?

Comment: [Sure](https://www.npoint.io/docs/a789f8b967ab90fd6ca4)

Comment: Why is there no `UniqueId` field in your mapping? Yes there are several `externalUniqueId` fields and one of them is of type `date`, that might be the culprit

Comment: externalUniqueId is UniqueId.

Comment: Ok, see my above comment then... in your mapping, one of those fields is of type `date`, which is causing the issue you're seeing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mapping contains several `externalUniqueId` fields (at different hierarchy levels), and all of them are of type `text/keyword`, except one which is of type `date` (in `parents.labour`).

That's the one causing the issue you're seeing. You need to fix the mapping of that field, and reindex the whole index in order to make this work.

Comment: it must be a bug of nest as the actual objects at all levels are represented by the same type.